# FPDF wrap text inside cell table

Tags: php, fpdf

Is there an easy way to wrap a string inside a cell table in FPDF? I found a couple of answers but they look a little hard coded. I am retrieving data from my database so need it to by dynamic.

Here is an image showing my progress so far. The text is overlapping, so I need to get the cells to grow in height as required.

[image]

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
$row_height = 6;
$header = 35;
$y_axis = $header + $row_height;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $col1= $row['col1'];
    $col2= $row['col2'];
    $col3= $row['col3'];

    if ($y_axis >= 275) { // new page
        $pdf->AddPage();
        tableHeader($pdf);
        $y_axis = $header + $row_height;
    }

    //List of items
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(10);

    $pdf->MultiCell(40,$row_height,$col1,1);
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(50);
    $pdf->MultiCell(60,$row_height,$col2,1);
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(110);
    $pdf->MultiCell(90,$row_height,$col3,1);

    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
}
```

Comment: Describe progress screenshot, and why the hardcoded solutions are not useful in these case.

Comment: Post code as well, you need to create a new line after the first cell  :  $pdf->Ln(30);

Comment: @iblamefish it is because I am retrieving data from database and I need the row height of cell to auto adjust

Answer (score 1):

Maybe FPDF's [`MultiCell`](http://fpdf.de/dokumentation/funktionsreferenz/multicell.html) method fits your needs.

This method allows printing text with line breaks. They can be automatic (as soon as the text reaches the right border of the cell) or explicit (via the `\n` character). As many cells as necessary are output, one below the other.
Text can be aligned, centered or justified. The cell block can be framed and the background painted.